# Tableau: 400011 error when publishing workbook previously downloaded with 'includeExtract=False'

Tags: tableau-api

I have a workbook. Datasource is embedded into workbook and uses 'Extract' (not a live connection). Datasource is connected to an Amazon Redshift (probably it's not important). I download workbook using Rest API without extract (includeExtract=False). Inside xml I replace datasource connection_url/username/password/schema. When I publish modified workbook back into another site I get 400011 error.

When Datasource uses live connection then everything works fine (so new datasource connection credentials are fine)!!!

What is wrong when datasource uses an extract? Why can't I publish a workbook without extract so new extract would be automatically regenerated based on the new datasource connection credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some similar issues while xml hacking for automating preset workbooks.

1. If you are making this extract from Redshift; when publishing your original workbook make sure that *Embed Password* is selected and that you allow refresh access.
2. (Take this one with a grain of salt) If you are downloading an extract version of the workbook and not including the extract, the xml may be looking to execute on that extract and not on the live connection variables. Try downloading a workbook with a live connection from a test database and replace the xml to the new live connection.

Comment: 1. Embedding password doesn't help and 'allow refresh access' option is not available for this type of datasource (redshift).
2. With live connection it works but I specifically need extract because live connection works very slowly.

Comment: @AntonFil if you need the extract, why are you setting 'includeExtract=False' set it to True and change your database connection, as you were doing above. Or simply publish it once manually and set up a recurring [extract refresh](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/qs_refresh_extracts.htm) on tableau server. As stated in [this article](https://tableauandbehold.com/2015/08/06/tableau-rest-api-400-error-response-code-400011/), you need to publish a datasource first and then connect the workbook. See the second bullet point.

Comment: I need to clone workbooks from one site to another site and replace connection credentials in the clones. Source workbooks use extract because live connection works very slowly. I set 'includeExtract=False' because extract can be very big and I don't want to download it. Moreover I don't need to download extract because after replacing connection credentials anyway this extract will be updated and it will be a different extract then. I need to implement solution which will do everything automatically, so I can't do anything manually.

Comment: @AntonFil "Publishing a TWB that references a data server source that doesn’t exist on that Site. Per the previous post on the topic, you can publish a TWB that connects to a data server source with the same name on a different site. But if you haven’t published the data source first, expect 400011 to be your fate"  - [this article](https://tableauandbehold.com/2015/08/06/tableau-rest-api-400-error-response-code-400011/) Maybe try [tabcmd](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm).

Comment: I tried to create a published datasource (not an embedded one). If I try to download/publish a published standalone datasource which uses extract then I get the same error 400011 when I download it with 'includeExtract=False'.

Comment: @AntonFil I understand what you are saying, I am no longer talking about embedded datasources. The above article is saying you are going to keep getting the 400011 error if your datasource does not *already* exist on the new site you are publishing to. Try using the API to publish *just* the new datasouce connection and then use your script to publish the workbook clones.